# Packages.json could not be downloaded, SSL Operation timed out (Composer)

Tags: drupal, composer-php, drush

I'm currently downloading `drush` using `Composer` on my `Drupal 8` Project and I'm having some issues during download as shown in the screenshot below. I have already installed composer globally and I'm not sure what else I'm missing

[image]

Comment: Can you try `curl https://packages.drupal.org/8/packages.json` to see whether your server can reach the drupal server?

Answer (score -2):

You have to install drush globally into root directory not in the drupal folder.

1. Install Composer globally.
2. Add composer's bin directory to the system path by placing export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH" into your ~/.bash_profile (Mac OS users) or into your ~/.bashrc (Linux users).
3. Install latest stable Drush: composer global require drush/drush.
4. Verify that Drush works: drush status.

you can try `composer global require drush/drush:8.x-dev` and update the composer as well.

Comment: How does this solve the problem that the server seems to be unavailable?

Comment: It's not about server it's about you are installing drush on wrong place, you have install it on the composer root dir.

Comment: Well, then you should probably have a look at the error message given in the screenshot...

Comment: Yes i have face same issue, you have to install it on right place.

Comment: You can enable open ssl in php ini but in my case when i run this command on the root dir, it works.

Comment: In the 2nd step mention that you have to run this command into `~/.bash_profile (Mac OS users)`.